# How do I print class objects based on an attribute value obtained from user input?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import attrgetter

class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, Question, task, reference, aAnswer, bAnswer, cAnswer, dAnswer, letterAnswer, Relevance):
        self.Question = Question
        self.task = task
        self.reference = reference
        self.aAnswer = aAnswer
        self.bAnswer = bAnswer
        self.cAnswer = cAnswer
        self.dAnswer = dAnswer
        self.letterAnswer = letterAnswer
        self.Relevance = Relevance

df = pd.read_excel('Test Bank 2021.xlsx')

questions = df.values.tolist()
question_instances = []
for p in questions:
    question_instances.append(Question(*p))
```

I've started the above project where I'm creating a testing program.  The object attributes are listed and self-explanatory.  The "Relevance" attribute references the different tests that are in the database of questions.

For example, if I wanted to issue someone a "Math" test, I would only want to pull from the objects with the "Math" value for the "Relevance" attribute.

I've tried googling this, but the only things that come up are how to print the attributes.  But what I want is to print the *other* attributes of the objects based on the value of the user input.

It would start something like this:

```
testName = Input("What test would you like to give? ")
testQuestions = Input("How many questions? ")
```

After this, I would want to filter the large (1000 item) "question_instances" list and select a random sample of questions based on the amount of questions selected, only taking from the questions in the correct relevance selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import random
import pandas as pd

class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, Question, task, reference, aAnswer, bAnswer, cAnswer, dAnswer, letterAnswer, Relevance):
        self.Question = Question
        self.task = task
        self.reference = reference
        self.aAnswer = aAnswer
        self.bAnswer = bAnswer
        self.cAnswer = cAnswer
        self.dAnswer = dAnswer
        self.letterAnswer = letterAnswer
        self.Relevance = Relevance

df = pd.read_excel('Test Bank 2021.xlsx')
questions = df.values.tolist()
question_instances = [Question(*p) for p in questions]

testName = input("What test would you like to give? ")
testQuestions = int(input("How many questions? "))

filtered_questions = [q for q in question_instances if q.Relevance == testName]
selected_questions = random.sample(filtered_questions, testQuestions)

for question in selected_questions:
    print(question.Question)
    print(question.aAnswer)
    print(question.bAnswer)
    print(question.cAnswer)
    print(question.dAnswer)
```

Comment: You made that look easy.  I need to study this more.  Thank you so much.  I'll get to work on the grading aspect of the test now.